# Lambda Expression for LINQ Select Items

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have this code

```
var list = _db.Projects.Where(item => item.Loc =="IN").Select(p => new {id=p.Id, title=p.Title,pc=p.PostalCode });
```

Project table having lot of columns, i need to query required columns dynamically and load from database, not all columns along with data.

Questions:

1. how to write lambda expressions for linq select ?
2. How to reduce data reads on database by selecting specific cols, entity framework ?

Comment: hmm...  It's not clear what you need since the code you posted seems to answer your own question.  can you be more specific?  Do you want the returned objects to be of a specific type?  Also unless you have some columns that store large amounts of data selecting fewer columns is unlikely to improve your performance noticeably.

Comment: Hi Ben Tidman, i need to build a select dynamic query with required fields. so i need to get dynamic code for .Select(p => new {id=p.Id, title=p.Title,pc=p.PostalCode }) using lamda expression or linq expressions no idea !

Comment: If you're going to create the anonymous type dynamically (which seems to be what you want), how are you going to access its members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the expression the C# compiler generated and try to replicate what it does:

```
Expression<Func<Project, object>> lambda =
    (Project p) => (object)new {id=p.Id, title=p.Title,pc=p.PostalCode };
```

I hope this code compiles. If not, you'll surely be able to fix it. Afterwards, look at the contents of the `lambda` variable.

Note, that the cast to `object` is only there to make this compile. You don't need/want that is production.

Comment: Hi usr, i need to change .Select(p => new {id=p.Id, title=p.Title,pc=p.PostalCode }); with required fields.

Comment: @RameshBolla Look at the expression the C# compiler generated so that you learn how it looks like. You have to build an expression yourself that only contains the required fields. Use the `Expression` class.